# ModuleNotFoundError even with __init__.py

Tags: python, module, file-structure

I have a project with the following structure:

```
.
└── project
     ├── assignment01
     |      ├── __init__.py
     |      └── old_file.py
     |
     ├── assignment02
     |      ├── __init__.py
     |      └── new_file.py
     └── __init__.py
```

I need to use a function that I implemented in the first assignment in the file `new_file.py` which I import as follows:

```py
from assignment01 import old_file as assgn1
```

When I want to run `new_file.py` in the command line it throws the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'assignment01'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to make both assignments be part of a package, by putting a `__init__.py` inside `project` and then doing `from ..assignment01 import old_file`.  You will need to call your code from above `project` (`python -m project.assignment1.newfile.main`) , so python picks up the outer package and is able to resolve `..`.  Or you can leave out the `..` and simply call from `project`, as noted in the other answer.  In any case the idea is to get `assignment0` somewhere that python can *find* it and import.

Or you need to add `project` to your `sys.path`:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path

sys.path.insert(0, str(Path(__file__).parent.parent))
```

Your current import fails because python is looking in `assignment02` for `assignment01` and, of course, failing.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to show, that I have also a ```__init__.py``` in the projects directory. Now, if I import it with ```from ..assignment01 import old_file```, I get the following error: ```ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package```

Comment: @MarcelloZago yes, for relative imports you need to be calling from the root package (or at least above the relative level).  I'l update

Answer (score 0):

Add another `__init__.py` in the `project` directory.

Also, with your code, try running `new_file.py` from your `project` directory.

Example:

```
python assignment02/new_file.py
```